# How to attach files to MS Word document using docx4j?

Tags: java, docx4j

Is there a way how to attach files into MS Word document? I mean the same way as you drag and drop e.g. MS Excel file into MS Word. It shows MS Excel icon and file name and double click opens attached document.

My situation comes from former html files that I import using XHTMLImporter.convert. Now HTML references attachments for download on several places and would like to attach these files into appropriate MS Word documents.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the filetype you want to embed.  Its a docx?  I'll update my answer with sample code if you clarify.

Comment: The attachments are  PDF, XLS and DOC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Plutext's Docx4j Enterprise Edition.

If you download the trial, see the section in the manual on "OLE Helper".

Comment: Just sent price request to sales@plutext.com